# Apache Camel FTP - What is the best practice between a context start and stop

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I wrote some code to download a file from an FTP site looks like below:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
          public void configure() {
              from( uri ).to( localBox );
          }
      });
    context.start();
    // a tedious sleepy thread !?
    // TODO: work around for a better solution
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    context.stop();
```

I am looking for a better solution instead of Thread.sleep method. Is it also possible to get how much time has left for finishing the transfer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main Answer

The syntax below will get you what you want without using *Thread.sleep*:

```
context.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(20000);
```

### Other Suggestions

This page has a few [other examples of ways to shutdown camel](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.4/eip/BasicPrinciples-StartupShutdown.html). However, if you're using these approaches, chances are that you're not using camel as intended. As @Petter said, Camel is typically used on a server that continuously runs.

Here, when we want to run a route in a "one-off" way, we usually just use the *Producer* as in:

```
@Required
protected ProducerTemplate producer;

public Object getObjectFromRoute(String routeId, Object payloadBody) {
    return producer.requestBody(routeId, payloadBody);
}
```

You can use a similar technique to send a message to a route who is responsible for shutting things down using DSLs like the `shutdownRoute` and `shutdownRunningTask` or some kind of `processor` who exits the app, gracefully.

Once you have a route like that in place, you can send your application the appropriate message that invokes this route and exits cleanly (Alternatively, using an instance of Camel's *Main* class and enabling *hangup support* takes care of this for you when you send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to your running application).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been experiencing with Apache Camel for about a week. As far as I read the docs and tutorials, it is intended to be used on a server as you said. I switched my technology choice to Jcraft's JSCH library and implemented a client works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually, you have this code embedded in some application that actually does keep running, such as a web application, some client gui application, in an OSGi bundle inside Apache SMX or whatnot.

There is, however, a standard way to do what you want with a stand alone Camel if this is the only code you want to run  (i.e. for a Batch job or similar). Read [this](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) article.